# Retrieving last record in each group filtering by date - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I need an upgrade from a problem already solved in another question: [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

My problem is very similar yet I cannot achieve the results I need.

In my first table `VAT_types` I define what kind of rates are available by their names

```
id   type
--------------
1    ordinaria
2    ridotta
3    minima
4    esente
```

In my second table `VAT_rates` I have multiple VAT rates according to when the law will make them official and those rates will be once in a while updated but a record of all rates must always be available

```
id  date        type rate
-----------------------------
1   2013-01-01  1    22.0000
2   2013-01-01  2    10.0000
3   2013-01-01  3     4.0000
4   2000-01-01  4     0.0000
9   2019-01-01  2    11.5000
10  2021-01-01  2    12.0000
11  2019-01-01  1    24.2000
12  2021-01-01  1    25.0000
```

So if I want to filter them accordin to the current date (or a future date) I just have to query them like this:

```
SELECT VAT.id, TYPE.type, VAT.date, VAT.rate
FROM VAT_rates VAT JOIN VAT_types TYPE on TYPE.id = VAT.type
WHERE cast(VAT.date as date) <= cast("2022-11-22" as date)
ORDER BY VAT.type ASC, VAT.date DESC
```

`"2022-11-22"` can be any date, and in fact if I change it to CURDATE() it will display all available rates until that date.

Now I want to group them by vat type and retrieve just the last updated one. So I looked up here and found that solution linked above which I tweaked like this:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM (
  SELECT VAT.id, TYPE.type, VAT.date, VAT.rate
  FROM VAT_rates VAT JOIN VAT_types TYPE on TYPE.id = VAT.type
  WHERE cast(VAT.date as date) <= cast("2022-11-22" as date)
  ORDER BY VAT.type ASC, VAT.date DESC
) T1
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT VAT.id, TYPE.type, VAT.date, VAT.rate
  FROM VAT_rates VAT JOIN VAT_types TYPE on TYPE.id = VAT.type
  WHERE cast(VAT.date as date) <= cast("2022-11-22" as date)
  ORDER BY VAT.type ASC, VAT.date DESC
) T2
ON (T1.type = T2.type AND T1.id < T2.id)
WHERE T2.id IS NULL
ORDER BY T1.rate DESC;
```

The result will be:

```
id  type      date       rate
--------------------------------
12  Ordinaria 2021-01-01 25,0000
10  Ridotta   2021-01-01 12,0000
3   Minima    2013-01-01  4,0000
4   Esente    2000-01-01  0,0000
```

It seems to work, but of course it's way too complicated. I also wish to use this query in my php and tweaking the date just once in order to retrieve the right rates and then the specific rate needed.

How can I simplify the query above?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a inner join on subquery for max date group by type

```
    select VAT.id, TYPE.type, VAT.date, VAT.rate
    from VAT_rates VAT
    inner JOIN VAT_types TYPE on TYPE.id = VAT.type
    inner join  (

        select max(VAT.date) max_date, TYPE.type
        from VAT_rates VAT
        INNER JOIN VAT_types TYPE on TYPE.id = VAT.type
        WHERE  str_to_date(VAT.date, '%Y-%m-%d')  <= str_to_date("2022-11-22",   '%Y-%m-%d')
        group by TYPE.type 


    ) T on T.max_date  = VAT.date and T.type = TYPE.type
```

Comment: This one has no closest to date search.

Comment: @RaymondNijland   data for search added

Comment: This throws an error on `inner JOIN VAT_types TYPE on TYPE.id = VAT.type` - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Comment: however if you add `FROM VAT_rates VAT` just before the first `INNER JOIN` it will work!

Comment: @dcdeiv Hey this is not a good solution. If I omit the syntax problems (that you already solved), it may return the wrong solution if you do not add the `cast(VAT.date as date) <= cast("2022-11-22" as date)` condition to the outer query as well.

Comment: @dcdeiv  .. thanks  .. (from  .. added) .. and use str_to_date too  ..instead of cast the string

Answer (score 1):

It is common to find the greatest per group using the following approach

```
select VAT.id, TYPE.type, VAT.date, VAT.rate
from VAT_rates VAT
join VAT_types TYPE on VAT.type = TYPE.id
join
(
    select type, max(date) max_date
    from VAT_rates 
    where cast(date as date) <= cast("2022-11-22" as date)
    group by type
) t on VAT.type = t.type and
       VAT.date = t.max_date and 
       cast(VAT.date as date) <= cast("2022-11-22" as date)
```

Comment: so I have to write twice the date